# Querying by parent model -- ".... is not a valid query expression"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a ParentModel, ChildModel1 and ChildModel2. ParentModel has many ChildModel1 and ChildModel1 has many ChildModel2.

Now, I want to show a list of ChildModel2 filtering by ChildModel1.parent_model.id. Here's a simplified code:

```
def index(conn, %{"parent_model_id" => parent_model_id}) do
  child_model2_items = where(ChildModel2, [x], x.child_model1.parent_model_id == parent_model_id)
  # ......
```

And I get an exception:

```
`x.child_model1().parent_model_id()` is not a valid query expression
```

Comment: You are going to have to use joins. You do not have access to `child_model1` within a query, only `x`'s attributes (which should include `child_model1_id`).